# Get form name by the click on submit button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
    app.directive('customToaster', function () {

        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                var foundButton = document.getElementByIds("buttonName2");    

                  foundButton.bind('click', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                      console.log('some text');
                    });
                });
              });
```

```html
<form name="someName2">
 <div> 
  <div> 
   <button type="submit" name="buttonName2">Submit2 </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

How I can get form name by the click on submit button using AngularJS.

```html
<form name="someName">
 <div> 
  <div> 
   <button type="submit">Submit </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Bear in mind that the number of nested div tags can be more than two.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.directive('customToaster', function () {

    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                $scope.inputClick = function(name) {
                    console.log("form name: " + name);
                }
         }
    }
    });

<form ng-model="someName2">
<div> 
    <div> 
    <button ng-click="inputClick(someName2)" type="submit" name="buttonName2">Submit2 </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually I created directive and I have an event 'click' on this button. I would like to know the name of the form where is this button applied. Something like this `var foundButton = element.find("button");    foundButton.bind('click', function () { ...}`

Comment: so pass the ngModel to the directive as a param on the click event

Comment: just create a function in your directive and attach ng-click to the input tag with the ngModel param